# Can create Hive external table location to external hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can I create hive database/external table locate to another hadoop cluster ?

hadoop_cluster1 -> run hive service
hadoop_cluster2 -> store data

```
create database mydata location 'hdfs://hadoop_cluster2/data/mydata'
```

or

```
create external table mytable1 location 'hdfs://hadoop_cluster2/data/mydata/mytable1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried it? I dont think it will work. But you can do data transfer with distcp between clustors.